# Cordova 3.4 doesn't include Amazon FireOS components and errors when trying to add the platform

Tags: cordova

I'm wanting to add Amazon FireOS support to my Android/iOS Cordova 3.4 app. 
However, when following the docs and using the command:

```
cordova platform add amazon-fireos
```

I get the following error because the fireos bin/create files don't seem to have been installed  - but I can't see anywhere that describes how to do this:

```
» cordova platform add amazon-fireos
Creating amazon-fireos project...
execvp(): No such file or directory
Error: /Users/tom/.cordova/lib/amazon-fireos/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/tom/.nvm/v0.10.24/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:787:12)
```

Is there an additional step to add the Cordova amazon-fireos components first?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been addressed here http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-issues/201404.mbox/%3CJIRA.12706268.1396466905012.56071.1396505297885@arcas%3E

The above fix will be available in 3.5.

To unblock yourself, you can create a 'libs' folder inside /Users/tom/.cordova/lib/amazon-fireos/cordova/3.4.0/framework/ directory and copy the awv_interface.jar into it. You can download the Amazon WebView SDK from here https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/IntegratingAWV.html.